# Trying to track how many times java script function is called

Tags: javascript, html

```
var totalEnteredCount = 0;
function totalEntered(field){
if(field.value != '')
{
    totalEnteredCount++;
}
alert(Count);
if(totalEnteredCount == 3)
{
    var IV = document.getElementById("IVUnit").value;
    var FV = document.getElementById("FVUnit").value;
    var Distance = document.getElementById("DUnit").value;
    var Acceleration = document.getElementById("AUnit").value;
    var Time = document.getElementById("TUnit").value;
}
}
```

This function is called onBlur from HTML, every time a textbox either has data entered or not. If data is entered, I want it to increment the totalEnteredCount by 1. However the global variable is undefined. Is there a way to track how many times the function is called?

HTML is below:

```
<td>Initial Velocity: </td>
       <td> <input type = "textbox" name ="InitVelocityInput" onKeyPress="return isAcceptable(event)" onBlur = "totalEntered(this)" id = "IVUnit"> </td>
```

Comment: please accept the answer that solved your problem so that the question can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Corrected code-**

```
var totalEnteredCount = 0;
function totalEntered(field)
{
    if(field.value !== '') //using !== instead of != for string comparision
    {
        totalEnteredCount++;
    }
    alert(totalEnteredCount); //using totalEnteredCount instead of Count
    if(totalEnteredCount == 3)
    {
        var IV = document.getElementById("IVUnit").value;
        var FV = document.getElementById("FVUnit").value;
        var Distance = document.getElementById("DUnit").value;
        var Acceleration = document.getElementById("AUnit").value;
        var Time = document.getElementById("TUnit").value;
    }
}
```

**JS Bin:** http://jsbin.com/xujugebeva/edit?html,js,output

Comment: every time i run this code on my site, the alert comes up as NaN, instead of returning the number like it does in this example. Thank you for your response

Comment: There must be some problem with the rest of your code. Cannot say anything about that without seeing it first.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to alert "Count" which is undefined: `alert(Count);`
This cause a runtime error and prevent the rest of the code from executing. Try to comment-out this line